# In Sphinx, how do I filter out the parents of the current page in the toctree?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm investigating Sphinx at the moment, and something I'm hoping to do is show a subset of the toctree on certain pages.

For example, imagine I have the following page structure:

- Overview
- Quick start
- Changelog
- Extension points

  - Content extensions

    - Quick start
    - Content types
    - Pagination
  - Editing extensions
  - Publish extensions

When I'm on the "Content extensions" page, I only want the sidebar to display links to its subpages:

- Quick start
- Content types
- Pagination

Is this possible?

Comment: This is dependent upon the Sphinx theme you choose. Which are you using? Check its documentation for how to show or hide navigation.